# How do I access items in arrays in generic classes?

Tags: c#

I have this csharp code;

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    interface Option<a>
    {
        b Visit<b>(Func<a, b> on_some, Func<b> on_none);
    }
    class None<a> : Option<a>{
        public None(){}

        public b Visit<b>(Func<a, b> on_some, Func<b> on_none)
        {
            return on_none();
        }
    }

    class Some<a> : Option<a>
    {
        public a v;

        public Some(a v) {
            this.v = v;
        }

        public b Visit<b>(Func<a, b> on_some, Func<b> on_none)
        {
            return on_some(v);
        }
    }

    class Simple{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var values_or_not = new Option<int>[]
            {
                new None<int>(),
                new Some<int>(10),
                new Some<int>(2),
                new None<int>()
            };
            var s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < values_or_not.Length; i = i + 1)
            {
                var x = values_or_not[i];
                Func<int, string> onSome = v => "Values: ";
                Func<string> onNone = () => "No Value";
                s = s + values_or_not[i].Visit<string>(onSome, onNone) + "; ";
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the final string output (s) to look like this;

> No Value; Values: 10; Values: 2; No Value;

So it needs to take the values given into the output string. Preferably in these three lines;

```
                Func<int, string> onSome = v => "Values: ";
                Func<string> onNone = () => "No Value";
                s = s + values_or_not[i].Visit<string>(onSome, onNone) + ";
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's the question and what do you mean by generic arrays? The code contains normal arrays. You can access their elements the same way you access any other array's elements. Is the question how to treat different types perhaps, possibly using pattern matching?

Comment: Do you mean you want us to fix your code? Maybe move the line `Console.WriteLine(s);` outside the for loop?

Comment: No, our teacher can't write cohesive questions and now me and some classmates are all sweaty and shit because of this program they wrote and its aids. The output that is necessary is provided above; No Value; Values: 10; Values: 2; No Value;

Comment: you already have answer(s), but - assuming your teacher wrote the above - they need to read up on accepted conventions for the language they are writing in .  That's just sloppy and hard to read in a number of ways.

Comment: Yes that is our problem aswell, we've barely been  taught anything about the language and we're supposed to make this this week so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you face has nothing to do with arrays. Since the field `v` is only contained in `Some<a>`, you cannot access it from a `Option<a>` object.

Change the `onSome` delegate to

```
Func<int, string> onSome = v => $"Value: {v}";
```

Move the `Console.WriteLine` out of the loop.

```
string s = "";
Func<int, string> onSome = v => $"Value: {v}";
Func<string> onNone = () => "No Value";
foreach (Option<int> option in values_or_not) {
    s += option.Visit<string>(onSome, onNone) + "; ";
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Also, you can assign the delegates before the loop, as they do not change. In `onSome`, `v` is just a parameter whose value is not defined yet. It will be assigned the actual value and `$"Value: {v}"` will be evaluated when the delegate is called.

Using a `foreach` loop is somewhat easier than using a `for` loop as it eliminates the need for an index variable and an indexed array access. Note that you could also replace the delegates by local functions.

```
string s = "";

string onSome(int v) => $"Value: {v}";
string onNone() => "No Value";

foreach (Option<int> option in values_or_not) {
    s += option.Visit(onSome, onNone) + "; ";
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

---

Another option is to check for the type in the loop; however, this is not a good object oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the actual problem is how to emulate F#'s discriminated unions and write different stuff for different types. You don't need the `Visit` method. In C# 7 and later you can use pattern matching, provided both types have a common base type which can easily be an empty interface, eg :

```
interface IOption<T> {}

public class None<T>:IOption<T>{}

public class Some<T>:IOption<T>
{
    public T Value {get;}

    public Some(T value)
    {
        Value=value;
    }

}
```

And then :

```
 var values = new IOption<int>[]
        {
            new None<int>(),
            new Some<int>(10),
            new Some<int>(2),
            new None<int>()
        };
 var str="";
 foreach(var it in values)
 {
     switch(it)
     {
         case Some<int> s:
             str+=$"Values: {s.Value};";
             break;
         case None<int> _:
             str+="No Value;";
             break;                 
     }
 }
```

**C# 8 and switch expressions**

C# 8 brings switch expressions which allow you to use almost the same syntax as you would in F# :

```
 foreach(var it in values)
 {
     str+= it switch {
         Some<int> s => $"Values: {s.Value};",
         None<int> _=>"No Value;"
     };
 }
```